# Under "Users": Search by country name would be nice...

Tags: feature-request

... so one can find fellow users from one's own country.

I've tried a search on "denmark" from here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users

Yields no results.

Answer (score 1):

This is not searchable within the site itself.  Once the site graduates out of beta status, it will be included in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).  You would be able to run a query on the location field there.

Answer (score 0):

As handy as it would be at times, this is not designed to be a social networking site so this information is not always easy to come by.

Aside from waiting for us to graduate from beta, you could also try using the API (which I *think* works for beta sites). Location information will come back via the [`users-by-ids`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/users-by-ids) method.

If you're not a dev then [StackUsers.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/1573/stackusers-com-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-but-were-afraid-to-ask-abou) seems to be the other alternative. Unfortunately it's not currently working for me.